# Where can I download cocos2d-x prebuilt binary?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I'm targeting cocos2d-x-3.4rc1 for my little game, but my laptop was in some bad mood recently. It crashed everytime I try to build cocos2d jni. So I figured maybe I could get a prebuilt binary somewhere, since everybody is talking about doing so.

So, is there anywhere I could download prebuilt binaries of cocos2d-x for android (armeabi/x86) for release/debug? How about win32?

Comment: If you laptop is crashing trying to do a build I believe your problems are broader than can be fixed by downloading the prebuilt framework. That said, the "Framework" builds of cocos2d-x, available using the Cocos (Studio) Launcher, include cocos2d-x in prebuilt form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a new project with prebuilt libraries using "Cocos": http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download and copy all assets/code or add them manually using this guide: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Cocos_gen-libs

Comment: It works very well with Cocos prebuilt libs. Thank you a lot.